# How can I tell if a specific AP has 802.11r enabled?

Tags: wifi

I'm trying to enable 802.11r on my OpenWRT APs. How can I confirm in Linux that the specific AP (by ESSID) has 802.11r enabled?

Answer (score 1):

From that [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/openwrt/comments/515oea/finally_got_80211r_roaming_working/)

> ## Howto check if my Device is capable?

On Linux, issue:

```bash
sudo wpa_cli scan
```

then a few seconds later

```bash
sudo wpa_cli scan_results
```

If your 802.11r AP shows up advertising "WPA2-PSK+FT", then your device likely supports 802.11r, FT stands for Fast Transition...

Answer (score 0):

## iwd

If you're using IWD you can see it when you run `iwctl station wlan0 show`, where `wlan0` is the station you're on

```
Security              WPA3-Personal + FT
```

FT means fast Transition, or 802.11r